# Dynamic array loop using sqlplus in bash unix

Tags: bash, unix

**I have a table having a few columns and I want to extract two columns RCRD_ID and ACCOUNT which I have sorted**

> RCRD_ID       ----->    ACCOUNT
>
> 630566DAD135E9A11 -----> JZZ35
>     630566DAD135E9A12 -----> EGC46
>   630566DAD135E9A13 -----> 85955
>    630566DAD135E9A14 -----> EGC36
>   630566DAD135E9A15 -----> 85044
>   630566DAD135E9A16 -----> JZZ53
>   630566DAD135E9A17 -----> 09686
>    630566DAD135E9A18 -----> 85044
>   630566DAD135E9A19 -----> JZZ53
>   630566DAD135E9A110 -----> 09686
>   630566DAD135E9A111 -----> 09686

I want to store this data in array in bash

```
declare -a my_array =`sqlplus -s "$SqlString"<<eof
set trimout on feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT RCRD_ID FROM ACCNT_DTLS WHERE EVNT_ID='$Event' ORDER BY LPAD(RCRD_ID, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(RCRD_ID)) FROM ACCNT_DTLS)) ASC;
EXIT;
eof`
```

Note: Above RCRD_ID  data is the output of this query

```
SELECT RCRD_ID FROM ACCNT_DTLS WHERE EVNT_ID='$Event' ORDER BY LPAD(RCRD_ID, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(RCRD_ID)) FROM ACCNT_DTLS)) ASC;
```

but when I am printing length of `my_array` it is returning always 1

as a result, I wanna print above data in XML format

```
#loop start

    echo "<RCRD_ID>$RCRD_ID</RCRD_ID>"      
    echo "<ACCOUNT>$ACCOUNT</ACCOUNT>"

#loop end
```

Example -

```
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A11</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>JZZ35</ACCOUNT>
```

I have tried to create an array and tried to and pass RCRD_ID to get ACCOUNT from ACCNT_DTLS in SQL query

Please assist me an optimized way to loop it dynamically and create a bash script to get data from database and print all  11 rows to generate XML

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net to validate your script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your database, so I put your query output in a file called `output.txt` and this seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a my_array=( $(cat output.txt) )

for ((i=3; i < ${#my_array[@]}; i+=3)); do
    RCRD_ID=${my_array[i]}
    ACCOUNT=${my_array[i+2]}
    printf "<RCRD_ID>%s</RCRD_ID>\n<ACCOUNT>%s</ACCOUNT>\n" "$RCRD_ID" "$ACCOUNT"
done
```

Output:

```
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A11</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>JZZ35</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A12</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>EGC46</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A13</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>85955</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A14</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>EGC36</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A15</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>85044</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A16</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>JZZ53</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A17</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>09686</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A18</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>85044</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A19</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>JZZ53</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A110</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>09686</ACCOUNT>
<RCRD_ID>630566DAD135E9A111</RCRD_ID>
<ACCOUNT>09686</ACCOUNT>
```

What you missed:

First, `declare -a my_array =` is not a shell assignment syntax - the `=` sign must have no surrounding spaces.

Second, the array syntax is `array=( ... )`, where the `...` part would be the output of your shell command, namely `$(sqlplus ...)`.

If you insist on using the `<< eof` syntax, then you can do something like:

```
declare -a my_array=( $(sqlplus -s "$SqlString" << eof
set trimout on feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT RCRD_ID FROM ACCNT_DTLS WHERE EVNT_ID='$Event' ORDER BY LPAD(RCRD_ID, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(RCRD_ID)) FROM ACCNT_DTLS)) ASC;
EXIT;
eof
```

Third, the output will be just a bunch of whitespace-separated tokens, and for your output, every 3 tokens together are the interesting unit of work, hence the `i+=3` part. The loops tarts at `i=3` because the first line - the first 3 tokens - are not what you want in the output.

Comment: you missed the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is array=($(command)).
I've written an example. I hope this can help you.

```
xml_str=''
first_column=true
res=($(sqlplus -s "$SqlString"<<eof
set trimout on feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
SELECT RCRD_ID FROM ACCNT_DTLS WHERE EVNT_ID='$Event' ORDER BY LPAD(RCRD_ID, (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(RCRD_ID)) FROM ACCNT_DTLS)) ASC;
EXIT;
eof))
for item in ${res[@]};do
        if ${first_column};then
                xml_str+="<RCRD_ID>$item</RCRD_ID>\n"
                first_column=false
        else
                xml_str+="<ACCOUNT>$item</ACCOUNT>\n"
                first_column=true
        fi
done
echo -e ${xml_str}
```